# Where is python supposed to install scripts for module

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a python module, and install a script as part of the installation of the package.
i.e. I have a script `foo`, and after the user installs the package, they should be able to run `foo` on the command line.

In the docs, it says:

> When we install the package, setuptools will copy the script to our PATH and make it available for general use.

[Source](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html)

Is it possible to find which folder the setup is supposed to install the script?

I have a setup.py that looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name="mymodule",
    version="0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
    scripts=['bin/foo']
)
```

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look [``console_scripts`` entry points](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/#entry-points-specification) for creating portable scripts. If you want to find an executable, that depends on your operating system/shell – for example on linux, use ``which foo`` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `entry_points` argument to `setup`;

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='bla'
    ...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['foo = foo.console:main']
    },
    ...
)
```

This is assuming the `foo` module contains a file `console.py` that has a `main` function.
Adjust according to your situation.

Note that you can have *multiple* console scripts if you want to. And you can also have `gui_scripts`.

On UNIX-like systems, the scripts end up in the `bin` subdirectory of the install prefix (accessible as `sys.prefix`). Often `/usr/local/bin`.

On ms-windows the scripts end up in the `Scripts` directory of your Python installation.

See also [here](https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/).

Answer (score 0):

Python's doc also says:

> The Distutils install command is designed to make installing module distributions to an alternate location simple and painless. The basic idea is that you supply a base directory for the installation, and the install command picks a set of directories (called an installation scheme) under this base directory in which to install files. The details differ across platforms, so read whichever of the following sections applies to you.
>
> Note that the various alternate installation schemes are mutually exclusive: you can pass --user, or --home, or --prefix and --exec-prefix, or --install-base and --install-platbase, but you can’t mix from these groups.

See it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/install/)

Comment: Hint: don't run `setup.py` directly. Use `pip install` instead, it will automaticaly runs your `setup` file